# How to make Highcharts Heatmap colors not gradient/percentage based, make the color value range based

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I want the colors to be like the Gitlab's Contribution Heatmap (bottom left is the color range):

[image: Gitlab's Contribution Heatmap]

```
// [value, color]
stops: [
    [0, '#ededed'],
    [1-9, '#acd5f2'],
    [10-19, '#7fa8c9'],
    [20-29, '#527ba0'],
    [30+, '#254e77']
]
```

Anyone know how can I do it with Highcharts Heatmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use data-classes for color-axis. For example:

```
  colorAxis: {
    ...,
    dataClasses: [{
      color: '#ededed',
      to: 1
    }, {
      color: '#acd5f2',
      from: 1,
      to: 9
    }, {
      color: '#7fa8c9',
      from: 10,
      to: 19
    }, {
      color: '#527ba0',
      from: 20,
      to: 29
    }, {
      color: '#254e77',
      from: 30
    }]
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9qd1Lewp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.dataClasses